# Can Vagrant be used with Windows Hyper-V Server?

Tags: vagrant, windows-server-2012, homestead, hyper-v

Is it possible to tell Vagrant to use a Windows Hyper-V Server as a host? I am currently using Vagrant for developing locally, which uses my development machine as the host.

The documentation for Vagrant mentions networking and ssh; however, this is almost always in the context of networking from the guest machine out. I am wondering how to run Vagrant on my desktop machine, and provision instances on the Windows Hyper-V Server.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step-by-step guide...

https://dogcomp.medium.com/speed-up-laravel-8-homestead-with-hyper-v-step-by-step-guide-99505199d003

The vagrant box provisioned is exposed in the local LAN subnet, as long as your firewall configured properly, you should be able to access via SSH/HTTP. However, you need to run `vagrant` command on the server.